# show image in "popup" with animation when clicking?

Tags: android, image, popup

I want to click on an image in my app and it get bigger and get in the foreground and the other part of screen become darker. Is it possible to do that  with an animation. I mean, like a popup in the android settings where i can tick different things, but only with my idea. So there is a picture instead settings. Or something similar. I can´t define it very good :D

Hope you understand me :D

Thanks in advance!

okay edit for better understanding:

I created an app with swipe view and tabs. Then i added some pictures with imageviews in one fragment. I know this feature from other apps: If i click on a picture, it zooms from its location in the center of the screen. You could compare it with halo from paranoid android.
I´ll for an example.

Code of Fragment1 with the picture:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {

            return null;
        }
        return (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,         false);

    }


 }
```

Comment: if you are unable to explain your question in a better way , please try to explain it in steps . Can you please do it now?

Answer (score 0):

i made example code to you as much as understand your request
you can use it like this

```
new Large_ImagePopup(<activity context>,< image url path >);
```

for example how to use it

```
new Large_ImagePopup(myclassname.class,"my image url link");
```

create new class `Large_ImagePopup.class` then create layout `dialog_mylargeimage.xml` add Imageview inside or anything you want

```
public class Large_ImagePopup extends Dialog {

Context context;


public Large_ImagePopup(Context context,String imageurl) {
super(context);

this.context = context;

//Set costume dialog information
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mylargeimage);//<< your xml layout for custome image popup

//get current screen h/w
Display d = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int w = d.getWidth();  
int h = d.getHeight();

//Set popup window h/w full screen or 98% it up to you
getWindow().setLayout((int)( w/100)*98, (int)( h/100)*98);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
setCancelable(true);  

//now get imageview inside custome dialog layout 
ImageView large = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.large);

//Show dialog
show();

//after you show dialog you can animate image zoom effect or anything you want to do with large imageview you can Google it how to animate imageview fade-in or zoom



  }
}
```

hope this useful to you

Comment: Hey,where should put this "new Large_ImagePopup(<activity context>,< image url path >);". In Large_ImagePopup.class?

Comment: Hey,where should put this "new Large_ImagePopup(<activity context>,< image url path >);"? And eclipse shows error in the 3 lines with "//get current screen h/w". Also i dont understand, what my activity context is?

Comment: add `onclicklistener` at your `imageview` then add `new Large_ImagePopup(this,"http://www.com.com/image.jpg");` this `Large_ImagePopup` is a custome class i made for you you have to create new class and add every thing in my answer and about the errors ill update my answer now

Comment: display.getHeight(); is deprecated. Should use getSize. Does your class works with getSize? And i dont understand "((Activity) context)". In eclipse this is an error.

Comment: import `Activity` in the class , `Context` is a class to register parent activity context information you have to use it to handle the popup dialog if you don't know how update your question with full code you are using then i can help

Comment: okay. Can you help me with adding on clicklistener and "new Large_ImagePopup(this,"http://www.com.com/image.jpg")" now? I don´t know how to put this in my code. :(

Comment: What code? I can only post your code again with a few changes.

Comment: the code you've created !! isn't ! your code main project where the images are added to swipview

Comment: this is done with xml not with a class. But i can post the code fot Fragment1

Comment: setOnclicklistener(this) is not applicable for Large_ImagePopup??